# How to use web service from a .NET Console

Tags: c#, database, web-services, asp.net-web-api, mapping

I succesfully read my records from a database table and I am putting the information in a List which type is `ClaimComment` (a class for mapping) because I need to put the information in a new database table.

```
using (var dbContext = new OldDbContextEntities())
{
    var claimComments = dbContext.R_ClaimHistory.ToList();
    var newDbContextClaimCommentsToSend = new List<ClaimComment>();
    foreach (var claimComment in claimComments)
    {
        var claimCommentToMigrate = new ClaimComment()
        {
            ClaimId = (int)claimComment.IdClaim,
            Comment = claimComment.HistClaimDescription,
            DateCreated = claimComment.DateCreated,
            UserCreated = (int)claimComment.IdUserCreated
        };
        newDbContextClaimCommentsToSend.Add(claimCommentToMigrate);
    }
    // continues below...
```

I need to  use Web Api in order to put the information in the database2 table.
I am starting like that:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54957/api/EntityMigration");
        var response = client.PostAsync("api/claimComment", newDbContextClaimCommentsToSend);
    }
```

But I am getting the error :

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HttpClient documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242(v=vs.118).aspx) is pretty clear that the second argument should be an HttpContent instance... consider taking a look at the [ObjectContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.objectcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) type.